# Stop IIS recompilation by removing Global.asax code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a pure Web API 2 project.  There's no .aspx or razor files.  However, I need a Global.asax file to configure things.  This causes IIS to recompile my site when its fired up.

Is there any way to move the Global.asax into a standard .cs file, which is included in my .dll?  I really want to speed up the time for a first request?

Comment: Have you considered [IIS Auto-Start](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) feature?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't you use Global.asax.cs?

Comment: @KonradKokosa Yes, I have.  But why do I need any compilation? I would like everything to be assembly or static files served up by IIS.

Comment: @RoyDictus, I want a simple speed up.  If I can get rid of Global.asax, then IIS wont compile my site.  This means no code behind files.

Comment: You could change your recycling setup. There will always be a delay when firing up the application the first time after recycle/build etc. Check out the comment from @KonradKokosa, and if you're running IIS8 there is an option to preload the applicationpool.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: If you precompile your site in Visual Studio and deploy it without sources, IIS will never need to recompile your site.

Comment: @scheien, I know there is always some delay in firing an app.  But why do I a need compilation? Is there some way to make IIS use my HttpApplication (in global.asax.cs) with out using code behind file>

Comment: @RichardSchneider - I'm not sure. According to the documentation (ASP.NET) the Global.asax is optional, but within a MVC project you have to do some wiring in the code behind; mainly application_start() event.